# TortoiseSVN unable to connect to VisualSVN

Tags: svn, connection, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server, visualsvn

Until last week we were normally able to connect to our VisualSVN server using Tortoise.

Yesterday it's not working anymore. Any attempt to connect results in error with message `Error running context: nenhuma conexão pôde ser feita porque a máquina de destino as recusou ativamente`. Yes, this portuga message means nothing and there are very few webpages talking about it.

Connection is made using HTTPS, I tried HTTP and SVN with no luck. I also tried to connect locally on the server, and strangely Tortoise hangs for some minutes and recovers reporting `Connection timed out`.

I tried restarting VisualSVN service. ALAIK firewall wasn't changed.

Strangely, if I use the same HTTPS URL on FireFox, it's answered and repository is shown as webpages!

Any idea on what may be causing this?

Update: I used [PortQry](https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/kb/310099) to connect to server using port 443, and it reported the port is listening. This means it's not a firewall issue and confirms FireFox being able to connect to VisualSVN. So, it's something related to TortoiseSVN.

Update 2: I tried command line `svn update` on my PC and got the same error message. Used the same command locally on the server, and it worked! This is getting strange.

Resuming: on my PC, both GUI and command line fail, but FireFox and PortQry work. Local on the server, command line works and GUI fails.

Comment: Any proxy settings in TortoiseSVN settings?

Comment: lol it worked now!! Thanks a lot! A long time ago I configured proxy to connect to my plan.io repository, looks like this week that proxy stopped working. I disabled proxy and it worked. If you add an answer I'll plus and mark it as answered.

Comment: Great! I'm glad it helped. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error can be translated to:

> no connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

In most cases the error indicates that you attempt connecting on incorrect port number or on HTTP port using HTTPS or vice verse. However, the error could also indicate invalid proxy settings configured for the Subversion client. Check the [proxy settings in TortoiseSVN](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html#tsvn-dug-settings-network).

Comment: Thanks a lot! You even translated the error message for me lol

Answer (score 0):

The permissions and port did not work for me.
I did a repair of the Visual SVN installation, by going into the control panel,

right click on Visual SVN > Repair
Took 2 minutes but it got the thing to work.

it was easier since it was a single server instance.